# How to remove the reoccuring events for a particular user in salesforce

Tags: tasks, lightning-events

How to remove the reoccuring events for 2 inactive users

Comment: I tried using data loader but it asks for a choose csv file. I do not have the csv file . I want to delete users based upon owner name. How do I procee

Comment: You need to export first. Remove the rows you don't want to delete, then re-upload as a delete job.